# Trouble with ConstraintLayout after migrating project to Androidx. Preview is greyed out, how can this be fixed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, androidx

After migrating my project in Android Studio to Androidx, my layout preview is now greyed out.

[This](https://imgur.com/9aUdec7) is what the preview looks like.

So far I have tried syncing the project, invalidating caches and restarting, creating a new layout and having the same problem persist.

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did you build project successfully?

Comment: Yes, build completes successfully with no errors.

Comment: Do you have the latest android studio and build tools? Also, have you tried right-clicking on the app folder and selecting an automatic migration to X, just in case you missed anything?

Comment: Bingo! I had missed the SDK Build-Tools and updating that did the trick, an oversight I'll be sure to check in the future. Thank you @Nikos

Comment: glad that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your theme to `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` by  adding a `Base` before.

Comment: Hmm... my project also appears to not recognise Base theme at all.